# How can I get strongly-typed higher order functions in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, higher-order-functions

See the below code block:

```
interface TestHiveInput {
  input: string;
}

interface TestHiveOutput {
  output: string;
}

type ListenFunction = (value: any) => void;

type Hive<T, K> = (initialValue: T) => {
  set: (newValue: T) => void;
  listen: (listenFunction: ListenFunction) => void;
};

type HiveFunction<T, K> = (input: T) => K;

type GetHive<T, K> = (hiveFn: HiveFunction<T, K>) => Hive<T, K>;

const hive: GetHive<any, any> = (hiveFn: (input: any) => any) => {
  return (initialInput: any) => {
    let _value = hiveFn(initialInput);
    const _listeners: Array<ListenFunction> = [];

    return {
      set: (value: any) => {
        _value = value;
        _listeners.forEach(listener => {
          listener(hiveFn(_value));
        });
      },
      listen: (listenFunction: ListenFunction) => {
        _listeners.push(listenFunction);
        listenFunction(hiveFn(initialInput));
      },
    };
  };
};

const myHive: Hive<TestHiveInput, TestHiveOutput> = hive(input => {
  return {output: input.input + input.input};
});
```

In defining the function `hive`, I had to give it the type `GetHive<any,any>` in order for the code to compile.

But, I'd like to have its input and output type inferred from `testHive`, which has its input and output passed (`TestHiveInput` and `TestHiveOutput`) to the `Hive` type.

In other words, I'd like automatic type completion on the function arguments I pass when calling the `hive` function. Id like to be able to write:

`const testHive: Hive<TestHiveInput, TestHiveOutput> = hive(input => { return {output: input.input + input.input}; });`

And have my IDE know the function `hive` expects a function as an argument with `TestHiveInput` as an argument, and which returns `TestHiveOutput`.

Thank you in advance

I am trying to write higher order function in Typescript which infers its types for the previously defined function type.

Comment: Just like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLAkvW)